# How to get a list of files (with filter) in folder with Win API

Tags: c++, file, winapi, directory

I have searched around the internet about getting list of files in a directory, but most answers required the boost library. So I make this question for those who don't want to add any third-party lib.

So how to get a list of files in a directory? and we can also decide the pattern of the files we gonna get (like all files, txt file only, file with specific text in file name, ...). Plus decide if search in sub-folder or not.

**Edit:** I see that this question get downgrade, maybe because I didn't specific that this question is for Win 32 instead of general C++ (I just realize recently that when I said C++, it's not necessary means Win API).

Anyway, in this question, I means to ask for Win API. Of course, general C++ is welcome though (because it can be used with Windows too, even better it's cross-platform).

Comment: Why not use `dirent.h`

Comment: @Sniper: Because there is no `dirent.h` for Windows, for example. And since the question is asking about a solution without adding third-party libraries, that's not a solution in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++17 has a [std::filesystem::directory_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator), which can be used as

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fis = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    std::string dir_path = "path_to_dir";
    for (auto & i : fis::directory_iterator(dir_path))
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Also, [std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator) can iterate the subdirectories as well.

**dirent.h** can be used which is also available for windows:

```
DIR *dir;
struct dirent *s_dir;
if ((dir = opendir ("c:\\programs\\")) != NULL) {
  /* print all the files and directories */
  while ((s_dir = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
    printf ("%s\n", s_dir->d_name);
  }
  closedir (dir);
} else {
  /* could not open directory */
  perror ("");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) But where is the pattern to search?

Comment: C++ 17 is cool, but it's only available in the compiler after year 2017. I don't have it :(

Answer (score -1):

So here is the functions

```
void GetSubfolderInDirectory(std::vector<TCHAR*> *lstFileOut, const TCHAR* szPath)
{
    HANDLE hFind;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA findData;

    TCHAR szCurrentDir[MAX_PATH];
    _tcscpy_s(szCurrentDir, MAX_PATH, szPath);

    TCHAR szPatternDir[MAX_PATH];
    _tcscpy_s(szPatternDir, MAX_PATH, szCurrentDir);
    _tcscat_s(szPatternDir, MAX_PATH, _T("/*"));
    TCHAR* szFullPath;
    bool bIsDirectory;
    if ((hFind = FindFirstFile(szPatternDir, &findData)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return;
    }
    do {
        bIsDirectory = (findData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) != 0;
        if (bIsDirectory)
        {
            if (findData.cFileName[0] == '.')
            {
                continue;
            }

            szFullPath = (_TCHAR*)malloc(_MAX_PATH * sizeof(_TCHAR));
            _tcscpy_s(szFullPath, MAX_PATH, szCurrentDir);
            _tcscat_s(szFullPath, MAX_PATH, _T("\\"));
            _tcscat_s(szFullPath, MAX_PATH, findData.cFileName);
            lstFileOut->push_back(szFullPath);
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &findData));
    FindClose(hFind);
}

void GetFilesInDirectory(std::vector<TCHAR*> *lstFileOut, const TCHAR* szPath, 
    const TCHAR* szPattern, bool bSearchSub)
{
    HANDLE hFind;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA findData;

    TCHAR szCurrentDir[MAX_PATH];
    _tcscpy_s(szCurrentDir, MAX_PATH, szPath);

    TCHAR szPatternDir[MAX_PATH];
    _tcscpy_s(szPatternDir, MAX_PATH, szCurrentDir);
    _tcscat_s(szPatternDir, MAX_PATH, _T("/"));
    _tcscat_s(szPatternDir, szPattern);

    if ((hFind = FindFirstFile(szPatternDir, &findData)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return; /* No files found */

    TCHAR* szFullPath;
    bool bIsDirectory;
    do {
        szFullPath = (_TCHAR*)malloc(_MAX_PATH * sizeof(_TCHAR));
        _tcscpy_s(szFullPath, MAX_PATH, szCurrentDir);
        _tcscat_s(szFullPath, MAX_PATH, _T("\\"));
        _tcscat_s(szFullPath, MAX_PATH, findData.cFileName);
        bIsDirectory = (findData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) != 0;

        if (findData.cFileName[0] == '.')
        {
            free(szFullPath);
            continue;
        }
        if (bIsDirectory)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            lstFileOut->push_back(szFullPath);
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &findData));
    FindClose(hFind);

    if (bSearchSub)
    {
        std::vector<TCHAR*> lstDir;
        GetSubfolderInDirectory(&lstDir, szCurrentDir);
        int nFolderCount = lstDir.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < nFolderCount; i++)
        {
            GetFilesInDirectory(lstFileOut, lstDir[i], szPattern, bSearchSub);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how to use

```
TCHAR szCrtPath[MAX_PATH];
TCHAR szCrtPattern[MAXBYTE];

_tcscpy_s(szCrtPattern, _T("*.*"));
_tcscpy_s(szCrtPath, _MAX_PATH, _T("D:\\MyFolder"));

vector<TCHAR*> lstFile;
GetFilesInDirectory(&lstFile, szCrtPath, szCrtPattern, true);
```

Some explanation about pattern

```
*.* // Get all files
*.txt // Get txt file only
*sometext* // Get file with "sometext" in size file name
```

Maybe there is a better way to get all sub-folder in the directory (function GetSubfolderInDirectory).

Comment: This is not standard C++. It uses Windows API functions.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: sorry, when writing this question I just think: third party -> non standard ; No third party -> standard

Comment: Well, is it your intention to provide an answer to this problem for general C++ code? Or is your intention to provide an answer for C++ on Windows? If the former, then your answer is wrong. If the latter, then change your question.